# Javascript on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

This is my code for Javascript:-

```
function show(ele)
    {
        a=document.getElementById(ele);
        if(a.style.display=='none')
        {
            a.style.display='initial';
            window.q="off";
        }
        else
        {
            a.style.display='none';
            window.q="on";
        }
    }
```

This does not run on Internet Explorer when called via 'onclick'. I use this simple function to show and hide elements.

Comment: You could have tracked this problem down by debugging it yourself. For instance you could have placed a breakpoint on the `a.style.display=`initial';` line. Then after single-stepping, examine the value of `a.style.display`, and you would find it was not changed (because IE did not accept the value). Or, after running the program, you could have viewed the element in the style inspector, and you would have seen that the value of `display` was still `none`, which would have given you a clue. Do you know how to use Chrome devtools, and its Source and Element views, or their Firefox equivalents?

Comment: Okay, will debug it next time if some similar issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
a.style.display='initial';
```

The style `display:initial` is not supported in IE. See the browser compatibility section here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

Use `display:block` instead. If you need to remember if the original display is `block` or `inline` use an object to keep track of the original display style or use data attributes attached to the element.